# What is the sum of the digits of $A$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A$ be a two digit number and $B$ be another two digit number formed by reversing the digits of $A$. 
If $A+B+$(Product of digits of number $A$) $= 145$, then what is the sum of the digits of $A$?

Comment: This needs a significantly better title.

Answer (score 1):

If $A = 10x+y$, then we have $11x+11y + xy = 145$, or $(11+x)(11+y) = 121+11x+11y+xy=121+145=266$.

There is only one way of factoring $266$ as the product of two integers larger than $10$, namely $14\cdot 19$.  So $\{11+x,11+y\} = \{14,19\}$, thus $\{x,y\} = \{3,8\}$, and the only possibilities for $A$ and $B$ are $38$ and $83$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on  the deduction.

Comment: @user375889 Which deduction?

Answer (score 1):

Let a be the first digit of A, and b be the second digit of A.

Without loss of generality we can assume that $a\le b$

$(10a + b) + (10 b + a) + ab = 145\\
11(a+b) + ab = 145$

Lets look at this modulo $11.$

$ab\equiv 2 \pmod {11}$

This leaves $12,38,46,57$ as possible solutions.

And $38$ is the only one that fits.